# Play video sound in Background (in Notification Bar) when App Closes Just Like VLC Player

Tags: android, audio, service, background, android-video-player

I have developed a video player application. Now I want to implement Background play functionality. I have checked many video player apps but none of them supports this. However, VLC does support this and when the activity goes in the background or stops then the video continue to play in the background as notification bar i.e. the sound continues to play with a video thumbnail shown in the Notification bar. When tapping on the notification bar it goes to the video page. This is what VLC does. 
I am unable to find any tutorial or guide to implementing this. Is it possible to implement something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Show some code what you have tried - that's almost mandatory for questions on SO...

If VLC has this feature then it is possible obviously :) Also YT, if you pay subscription

Also you may check source code of VLC in [HERE](https://github.com/videolan/vlc). For sure it is `Service`-based implementation, if your app is just simple player then you have probably `Activity`-based arch and you should migrate to `Service`